# MailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor is NULL on Outlook 2013 AddIn all the time

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-office, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

We have a C# Outlook Add-in which allows end user to click one button in Ribbon to insert some contents on new email. We are using MailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor to do so. However the weird thing is that our program is not able to get the WordEditor all the time. So far, it is only on my machine.

we would get exception like this

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x9CD04005): The operation failed.
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Inspector.get_WordEditor()
```

the last 4 digit is always 4005 while the first 4 could be changing. The first 4 should refer to the component where the error occurred.

I installed the outlookspy on my machine and it could not get WordEditor as well.
[image]

I did some search over internet and found out this link: [system.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xB5904005): The operation failed](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/79fe8341-e90f-409f-bcac-7ddaf4a187f8/systemruntimeinteropservicescomexception-0xb5904005-the-operation-failed-at?forum=vsto), so it suggests that we would get the WordEditor on Activate event to make sure WordEditor is fully initialized, however on new email, it should already be activated per our understanding unless we are missing something here. Plus I have run OUtlookSpy multiple times on a new email and each time WordEditor is null there. So it seems that it should not be initialization issue.

Could someone shed some lights on what we should investigate here?

Comment: Do you have Word installed on the machine?

Comment: Yes word 2013.  Here are detailed version information: Microsoft word 2013 ( 15.0.4797.1000) MSO (15.0.4787.1002) 32-bit  Part of Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013.   Our Outlook AddIn is also 32 bit and my machine is 64 bit.

Comment: Is reinstalling Office an option?

Comment: that's what I am thinking as well, let me work with IT team to do so.

Comment: Hi, @DmitryStreblechenko  by the way, is there anyway to turn on some verbose logging to see more information? Thanks again.

Comment: Do you mean in Outlook? I don't think so.

Comment: yep, got it. thanks.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko, I uninstalled the Office 2013 and reinstalled, unfortunately I still got same issue at OutlookSpy.  I didn't not reboot the machine though.

Comment: just restart machine, it is not helping as well. One thing I do feel that re-installation of Office 2013 went much faster than I thought based on my last fresh installation experience which leads me to think that Office 2013 uninstall won't clean up all files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may find my solution a bit odd, but it worked.

"Microsoft VBA for Outlook Addin" appeared to be disabled for some reason. I enabled it and the problem disappeared.

To be honest, I can't find a logical explanation for this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with our addin: A customer in a "secure enviroment" made some [restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/support-for-keeping-add-ins-enabled). Our addin did run, but each access to `WordEditor` resulted in a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005)`. This was a very strange behavior and I couldn't explain it.

After we also enabled the "Microsoft VBA for Outlook Addin" (ProgId Microsoft.VbaAddinForOutlook.1) it worked (just like Dobry suggested).